# Talend component tMicrosoftCrmOutput : Management of lookup fields for CRM Microsoft Dynamics 2015 ON PREMISE

Tags: talend

T.O.S for ESB, Version (6.0.0.20150702_1326)

I switch from an ON LINE 2011 option of the tMicrosoftCrmOutput (Microsoft Dynamics CRM) Talend component  connector to the ON PREMISE CRM 2015  option.

I did not see any more the lookup fields management (at the bottom of the Simple Parameter tab window).

How do I now manage these lookup fields ?

The problem is that it  is not compiling with database type LOOKUP  :

(type mismatch cannot convert from String to Document, the method setId(Guid) in the type EntityReference is not applicable for the arguments (void)

and this is not working  with databases type STRING or GUID  :(InvalidTypeCast)

(runtime error :com.microsoft.schemas.xrm._2011.contracts.services.IOrganizationServiceUpdateOrganizationServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage: System.InvalidCastException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #C61D300A)

I don't understand which is the correct format of the wished data (maybe an entity reference xml ? ), and which is the correct database type.

I have no solution. Has somebody an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after looking the Java code generated by Talend (no documentation !!!!), and make tests :

1) Upgrade to TOS for ESB version 6.1

2) you must put a XML structure value in the lookup field (Java type : String, Database type : LOOKUP), with the guid of the object (the foreign key/lookup identifier), and the logical name of the foreign table/entity (you do not need to fill the field name), exemple :

```
"<entity_reference><guid>222f7f2c-b392-e511-80c3-005056923d91</guid><logical_name>account</logical_name><name></name></entity_reference>"
```

Do not put carriage return into the string.
Hope it may help somebody.